# cloning or otherwise preserving click events using highslide htmlExpand

Tags: jquery, highslide

I have a problem here using highslide to expand several divcontainers. The containers are loaded directly into the html page and are invisible until expanded by highslide. The first time I expand a container, all my jQuery click events are fully functional. The problem is that in subsequent openings of the same container, those click events are no longer working.

The original divcontainer (including its changes triggered by one of my click events) seems to be removed from the source completely.

Is there any way to preserve the original divcontainers and the attached click events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this problem a moment ago.

Apparently highslide has discontinued deep cloning so it's impossible to maintain the .click() events. Simple solution was to use .on() instead. All works fine now.